# jQuery - use not() selector with regex expression

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display the first table and hide the others, for that I used `not()` selector but all tables are still displayed:

**HTML**

```
<table class="myTable" id="notThis">
...
<table class="myTable2">
...
<table class="myTable3">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("table[class^='myTable:not(#notThis)']").hide();
```

Comment: I don't you you could call that some kind of `RegEx`, `RegEx` is much more powerful, the attribute selector supports only the `^`, `$` and some other non-regex-related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$("table[class^='myTable']").not('#notThis').hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAG6Y/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the attribute selector before using :not()

```
$("table[class^='myTable']:not(#notThis)").hide();
//                      ^^
```